# CSS3 Animation - Infinite Hover Arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate a background image so that when you hover a link it infinitely (as long as you're hovered over the link) will move back and forth between 905 and 100%. I created a JSFiddle to play in but it doesn't really transition into any animation, but instead just kind of moves the background. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMdJu/)

**CSS**

```
a{display: block; background: url('thin-right-arrow.png') no-repeat right center; widht: 100%:}

a                   {background-position: 90% center;}

a:hover     {background-position: 100% center; -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;} 

@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 90% center; }
    to { background-position: 100% center; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needed `@-webkit-keyframes animate` for the animation to work in `-webkit` browsers.

<sub>*Note*, I haven't added any other vendors, so it will **only** work in `-webkit` browsers.</sub>

There is no need for JS/jQuery if you want the animation to last **while** hovering over the link [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/VCMa6/2/). However, if you want the animation to start upon hovering over the link, and then go infinitely, here is the jQuery based solution: [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/e5NwG/1/)

jQuery:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('animate');
});
```

CSS:

```
.animate {
    background-position: 90% center;
    -webkit-animation: animate 4s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    50% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a `from to from` so that it doens't jump back but animates back?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Alright, take a look at it now.. updated the links.. there are two options, both of which are smooth.

Answer (score 5):

First, you have your animation really slow at 40 seconds. Second you need to include all the vendor prefixed versions of keyframes. You just forgot `-webkit` keyframes.

**Note: No need for jquery/javascript**

If you want the arrow to return smoothly after un-hover just add `transition` and its vendor prefixed buddies

Edit: It seems you want a smooth back and forth when hovering and not just a smooth continuous in one direction. Same exact concept just change the keyframes:

## Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/SMdJu/10/)

```
a {
    background-position: 90% center;

    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
    -o-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
    transition: background-position 0.3s linear;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}

a:hover {
    background-position: 100% center;

    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: animatedBackground 2s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 2s infinite linear;
    animation: animatedBackground 2s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
}
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
}
```

Here is the continuous (to the right) arrow version:

## Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/SMdJu/9/)

```
a {
    background-position: 90% center;

    -webkit-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
    -moz-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
    -o-transition: background-position 0.3s linear;  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
    transition: background-position 0.3s linear;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}

a:hover {
    background-position: 100% center;

    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: animatedBackground 2s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 2s infinite linear;
    animation: animatedBackground 2s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
}
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% {
        background-position: 90% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 100% center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, the CSS version, fades all the arrows at the same time on  my current version of Chrome 32